# JS Detect Offline? What Am I doing wrong

Tags: javascript, html, offline

I'm a JS newb so I'm trying to figure out how to make this example from w3c to work in my WebApp that will run in a PhoneGap framework...

I'm sure this is easy, but when the event listener is triggered, it runs the attached function with the alert, problem is is it proceeds to excute everything after that again. So say I flip my iphone off, I'll get an alert then it will execute the next alert which says its online... Anywho... If any of you gys have any better ideas about executing a function like this let me know PhoneGap Cordova has two other methods as well.

```
<script>
<!--
window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {alert("offline");})
window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {alert("online");})
if (navigator.onLine) {
  alert('online')
  //functions to run online
} else {
  alert('offline');
  //offline functions or through into loop
}
-->
</script>
```

Comment: did got any answer for it? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parameter in the addEventListener function.
For me this is working fine:

```
window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
    console.log("Online status: " + navigator.onLine);
}, false);

window.addEventListener("online", function () {
    console.log("Online status: " + navigator.onLine);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this   `if(window.navigator.onLine) { alert('I am online');}`  I have just tested it in console and it works :)

Comment: thanks, but that's pretty much what I had... Problem is my addEventListener are messed up... I can't figure out how to compartmentalize them so that when it goes off it doesn't run all the scripts below it. So with 'window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {alert("offline");})
window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {alert("online");})' The online alert will run after the offline alert goes off... I'm sure this is really simple I'm just not familar with eventlisterners.

Comment: Here's an example:window.addEventListener("offline", function(off) {
                             alert("offline");
                             }, false);
    
    window.addEventListener("online", function(on) {
                            alert("online");
                            }, false);
If I run this it will trip both events whether I run it off or on. it will always trip Offline first and then Online. Help?

Comment: figured it out... It works fine. Except in the iOS Simulator.. Then it epically fails

Comment: You may want to check out [Offline.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline), a library created to solve just this problem.